# Как получить доступ к данным аккаунта двум приложениям?

Tags: android

У меня есть два приложения. Одно главное приложение а другое вспомогательное (лайт версия). В главном приложении реализована механика сохранения аккаунта при помощи AccountManager. Два приложения будут выложены с одного аккаунта google play. Главное приложение уже опубликовано.

**Цель:** Нужно что бы лайт версия получила доступ к аккаунту главного приложения через AccountManager. 
Погуглив я получил ответ что необходимо подписать два приложения одинаковой подписью. Подписать оба приложеиня одной подписью мне удалось. Но при публикации лайт прилоджения в google play я получаю следующюю ошибку: 
"Загруженный APK-файл или набор Android App Bundle подписан с помощью ключа, который уже используется в других APK-файлах. В соответствии с правилами использования функции подписания приложений Google Play вам необходимо подписать его с помощью нового ключа, а затем загрузить его снова."

**Вопрос:** Как подписать оба приложения одной подписью для доступа лайт версии к аккаунту главного приложения и опубликовать его в google play?

**Вопрос:** Как я могу обеспечить доступ к общей учетной записи с помощью accountManager и опубликовать приложение?

Comment: Примерно такая механика реализована у приложений Яндекс. У них  в настройки -> аккаунты -> есть один аккаунт от Яндекс и все приложения Яндекс (музыка, почта и другие) используют один аккаунт. Смысл этого всего такой что ненужно авторизовываться каждый раз в новом приложении.